# Is this a LQGI controller - Linear Quadratic Gaussian Integral regulator

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, optimal-control, kalman-filter

I want to make sure that I have done it right.

[image]

First of all, I going to show how I think the state space representation whould look like:

The System:
$$\dot{x} = Ax + Bu + I_dd$$
$$ y = Cx + I_n n$$

Where $I_n$ is the identity matrix for the noise and $I_d$ is the identity matrix for the disturbance. For SISO system $I_n = 1$

The LQE:
$$\dot{\hat{x}} = A\hat{x} + Bu + Ke$$
$$\hat{y} = C\hat{x}$$
$$e = y - \hat{y} = Cx + I_n n - C\hat{x}$$

The LQR:
$$ u = -L\hat{x} + L_i x_i$$

The LQI:
$$ \boxed{\dot{x_i} = I_r r - y = I_r r - Cx - I_n n}$$
$$ x_i = \int_{0}^{t} (I_r r- y)dt = \int_{0}^{t} (I_r r - Cx - I_n n)dt = \int_{0}^{t} = \dot{x_i} dt$$

Where $I_r$ is the identity matrix for the reference signal. For SISO system $I_r = 1$

Assume that:
$$\tilde{x} = x - \hat{x} \rightarrow \tilde{x} - x = - \hat{x} $$

Inserting that in LQR results the new $u$:
$$u = -L\hat{x} + L_i x_i \rightarrow  L\tilde{x} - Lx + L_i x_i$$

Inserting the new $u$ in System results:
$$\dot{x} = Ax + B(L\tilde{x} - Lx + L_i x_i) + I_dd$$
$$\dot{x} = Ax + B L\tilde{x} - BLx + B L_i x_i + I_dd$$
$$\boxed{\dot{x} = (A- BL)x + B L\tilde{x} + B L_i x_i + I_dd}$$

Inserting new $u$ and $e$ in LQE results:
$$\dot{\hat{x}} = A\hat{x} + B(L\tilde{x} - Lx + L_i x_i) + K(Cx + I_n n - C\hat{x})$$
$$\dot{\hat{x}} = A\hat{x} + B L\tilde{x} - B Lx + B L_i x_i + K Cx + KI_n n - K C\hat{x}$$
Assume that:
$$\dot{\tilde{x}} = \dot{x} - \dot{\hat{x}}$$

That means:
$$\dot{\tilde{x}} = [Ax + B L\tilde{x} - BLx + B L_i x_i + I_dd] - [A\hat{x} + B L\tilde{x} - B Lx + B L_i x_i + K Cx + KI_n n - K C\hat{x}]$$
$$\dot{\tilde{x}} = Ax + B L\tilde{x} - BLx + B L_i x_i + I_dd - A\hat{x} - B L\tilde{x} + B Lx - B L_i x_i - K Cx - KI_n n + K C\hat{x}$$
$$\dot{\tilde{x}} = Ax + I_dd - A\hat{x} - K Cx - KI_n n + K C\hat{x}$$

But remember that:
$$\tilde{x} = x - \hat{x}$$

Will give us:
$$\dot{\tilde{x}} = Ax + I_dd - A\hat{x} - K Cx - KI_n n + K C\hat{x}$$
$$\dot{\tilde{x}} = A(x - \hat{x}) + I_dd  - KC(x -\hat{x}) - KI_n n$$
$$\dot{\tilde{x}} = A\tilde{x} + I_dd  - KC\tilde{x} - KI_n n$$
$$\boxed{\dot{\tilde{x}} = (A - KC)\tilde{x} + I_dd - KI_n n}$$

**Result:**
The whole state space representation will be:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}\\ 
\dot{\tilde{x}}\\ 
\dot{x_i}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A-BL & BL  & BL_i \\ 
0 & A-KC & 0\\ 
-C & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
\tilde{x}\\ 
x_i
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
0 & I_d & 0\\ 
0 & I_d & -K I_n\\ 
I_r & 0 & -I_n
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
r\\ 
d\\ 
n
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$y = \begin{bmatrix}
C & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
\tilde{x}\\ 
x_i
\end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & I_n
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
r\\ 
d\\ 
n
\end{bmatrix}$$

**Questions:**

1. Am I wrong or Am I right? Is this the Linear Quadratic Gaussian Integral regulator?
2. Is there any way to compute the integral gain matrix $L_i$ by using Algebratic Riccati Equation (ARE)?
3. Will this regulator remove the steady state error?
4. What is the transfer function for this state space?

Source:
https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Mataveid/
https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Matavecontrol

Comment: 1 - Just taking a quick look, it seems fine. 2 - You can calculate de integral effect gain trought an ARE, what you will get is an extended gain matrix in which some columns of it are the feedback gain and the remaining columns are the integral gain. 3 - This regulator should be able to eliminate the steady-state error, because of the LQI.

Comment: Also, refer to my question about extended state-spaces for integral action (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2300177/optimal-control-in-tracking-problem)

Comment: Thanks! That was fast! Can I use the same lqr() command from MATLAB to compute $L_i$ as I do with the control law $L$ ? Just changing the $Q$ and $R$ weighting matrices?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson If you are using MATLAB, then why not use [lqi()](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lqi.html)?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson fibonatic's suggestion is also good. But indeed, you can use Matlab's lqr() to compute the gain. Just make sure to use matrices A,B,C and Q correctly (regarding extended state-space)

Comment: The main difference, if i'm not mistaken, is that lqi() will already return the separate gain matrices. With lqr(), you will need to separate them by yourself.

Comment: @fibonatic     because $lqi()$ is not LQGI :) And I don't have a MATLAB license. I use GNU octave Control Package.

Comment: @bertozzijr   Sorry. Using GNU Octave here :)

Comment: @DanielMårtensson, no problem! On Octave, try to solve the ARE through care(), then find the gain matrix using the solution for the Riccati equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [certainty equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_control#Certainty_equivalence) you can split the observer and feedback control up into two separate problems. So the full state observer can indeed be found using a Kalman filter/LQE. For the control [LQI](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/lqi.html) can be used, which tries to minimize

$$
J(u) = \int_0^\infty \left[z^\top(t)\,Q\,z(t) + u^\top(t)\,R\,u(t) + 2\,z^\top(t)\,S\,u(t)\right] dt, \tag{1}
$$

with $z(t) = \begin{bmatrix}x^\top(t) & x_i^\top(t)\end{bmatrix}^\top$ and $x_i(t)=\int (r-y)dt$. So using the standard state space model (without the feed through matrix $D$) and augmenting the state space yields

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x} \\ \dot{x}_i
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 \\ -C & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ x_i
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
B \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} u. \tag{2}
$$

The combined optimization problem using $(1)$ and $(2)$ can just be solved with [LQR](https://octave.sourceforge.io/control/function/lqr.html). However I am not entirely sure myself why your are allows to disregard the reference input from $(2)$.

Comment: That's not LQGI. That's LQI.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I do indeed mainly talk about finding the feedback gain from the LQI problem (so how to find your $L$ and $L_i$). However as stated at the beginning of my answer due to certainty equivalence you can split up finding the observer and feedback gain. I am not sure if there is a clear definition for LQGI, because you could also use $x_i = \int(r-\hat{y})\,dt$, so $\hat{y}$ instead of $y$.

Comment: So you mean that I could only use one row of the kalman gain or control law gain matrix?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I am not sure what you mean, what do you want to use that row for? Are you referring to $L_i$? In that case you can use the first column of the control law gain matrix.

Comment: For an example. If I want to compute the control Law, a.k.a LQR gain matrix. In MATLAB/Octave I can do this: $$L = lqr(A, B, Q, R)$$. And if I want to compute the kalman gain matrix, a.k.a LQE gain matrix. I use $$K = (lqr(A', C', Q, R))' $$ Notice that find the transpose of the LQR matrix to turn it vertical. What if I don't do that, then I would find a gain matrix for the $y$ outputs? So LQI gain matrix would simply be: $$L_i = lqr(A', C', Q, R) $$

Comment: Or isin't it better if I include integration inside the model? $$G(s) = \frac{1}{s + \epsilon}$$

Comment: I think I will use this: $$L_i = C*(lqr(A', C', Q, R))' $$ It will give one real constant if $C$ has one row.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson No, what I tried to say in my answer is that:
$$
[L\quad L_i] = \text{lqr}(A^*,B^*,Q,R)
$$

with

$$
A^* = \begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 \\ -C & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
B^* = \begin{bmatrix}
B \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: So adding integral into the model. Does C need to have the sime row size as A in this case?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Yes, since it is from your original state space model.

Comment: That mean if A is 2x2 then C need to be 2x2 too and this result that Li going to be 1x2 matrix. What If just had one output? One measurement?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson C does not need to have the same dimensions as A, it just needs to have the same number of columns as A. And indeed the number of rows of C determines the number of outputs the system has.

Comment: So I can say that $C = [1, 0]$ and $A = [0 , 1; -3, -5]$  and the LQR command says that it's OK?

Comment: so all I need to do is assume that the LQI gain matrix $L_i$ can replace the LQR gain matrix control law $L$? For example. Insted of only use $L$, I use $L^* = [L, L_i]$. This new gain matrix are for the estimated states.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68035/discussion-between-kwin-van-der-veen-and-daniel-martensson).